# Why is gStreamer throwing an error from waylandsink?

Tags: gstreamer, google-coral

I'm working on the Smart Birdfeeder project (https://github.com/google-coral/project-birdfeeder)
When running birdfeeder.sh with Coral camera on the Dev Board, I get:

** (python3:3933): CRITICAL **: 16:37:50.961: Failed to flush Wayland connection

The error streams up in the Terminal window and overwhelms the output until I ^Z out of the program. The number following "python3:" is constant for a given run but will be different in different runs.
If I plug a video monitor into the HDMI socket on the board and run the program, the real time image from the camera is shown in the monitor and if I hold a photo of a bird in front of the camera, the program works and an image from the camera is saved and the correct identification of the bird is written to the log file.
Here is the pipeline code:

```
def run_pipeline(user_function,
                     src_size=(640,480),
                     appsink_size=(320, 180)):
        PIPELINE = 'v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! {src_caps} ! {leaky_q}  ! tee name=t'
        if detectCoralDevBoard():

        # Test framerate of 1/1 on 200212 (line 69), then 10/1 back to 30/1

            SRC_CAPS = 'video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width={width},height={height},framerate=30/1'
            PIPELINE += """
                t. ! {leaky_q} ! glupload ! glfilterbin filter=glcolorscale
                   ! {dl_caps} ! videoconvert ! {sink_caps} ! {sink_element}
                t. ! {leaky_q} ! glupload ! glfilterbin filter=glcolorscale
                   ! rsvgoverlay name=overlay ! waylandsink
            """
```

I am inexperienced with gstreamer and could use any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone struggling to get GStreamer on Coral Dev-Board running in headless mode and without an active terminal session (registered as Systemd service or alike). 
There is one bad hack which I found (and which is now also included in newer Coral example code in a similar way):

```
os.environ["XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"] = "/run/user/1000"
```

Put this in the python code where you put together the GStreamer pipeline.

Another thing I have seen in some Google code before was the injection of messages into the gstreamer bus to please the one element which asks out for the current display.

Answer (score 1):

Good question BUT I'm not familiar with the program and do not have a monitor on my coralboard.  However, here are some ideas for you to start investigating.  I'm just getting into gstreamer (GST) and I think it's pretty cool!

1. The PIPELINE string is fed into the GST parser to build a processing data stream.  Each step of the pipeline is separated by a bang(!) and can be either a plugin or an internal capability.  The pipeline in the example is fairly complex and I suspect some of the steps are unnecessary.  It looks like there is a single source - the coralboard camera, and two sinks.  Each reference to `t.` is a new processing thread: one goes to the `{sink_element}` (which is a string defined somewhere in the python script) and another goes to `waylandsink`.  The elements between the source and sink take the sink of the prior element in the pipeline as the source and do some kind of conversion.  For example, the `videoconvert` plugin is used a lot to magically convert an source video signal to one that can be consumed by the sink. `glupload` is an opengl plugin that converts the video to opengl shading (I'm not clear if this is necessary.)  I don't recognize some of the other plugins.
2. My guess is the `waylandsink` plugin is throwing your error.  You can see the docs at [waylandsink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/waylandsink/index.html?gi-language=python).  You may need to look at the C source to understand why it is generating a CRITICAL error but if the video is being displayed on a local monitor it shouldn't be CRITICAL.
3. The NNN number in the `python3:NNN` string is the process ID of the python thread.  Probably not meaningful to you but GST is heavily multi-threaded, so helpful for debugging.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.

Comment: The investigation started months ago during which I've pieced together much of what you've stated above in #1. The pipeline should be prepping the INPUT to the TensorFlow inference engine. One must be the 320x180 image but I'm not sure what the second is. I am entrenched in #2 trying to understand what makes the Wayland sink angry when there's no monitor attached. There will NOT be when it is deployed.

Comment: PS: #3 was VERY informative. I am not an experienced Python programmer but have programmed in an number of other langs.

Comment: I see.Yes, the first thread is the image itself.  The second is an rsvg overlay (google it) based on the TPU object detection, probably a bounding box and text for the detected object.  Wayland is a window manager, which needs a GUI.

Comment: I see.  Wayland is a window manager, that needs a GUI.  I suspect if there is no display output it is generating a critical error.  If no HDMI signal then you need to stream output to a remote system.  Use RTSP envelope and udpsink to stream; udpsrc to receive on remote server.  Lot's of examples to do this on the web.

Comment: This code is provided as part of the "Smart Birdfeeder" project on-line for the Coral Dev Board and camera. It is intended to be deployed out of doors. Odd that a GStream element requiring a monitor would be used in the code.

Comment: Yes.  A lot of their demo code is pretty crude.  I think they were scrambling to get the product out.  I have a similar requirement; I use an RTP video streamer on the target (`! rtp263pay ! udpsink host=<ip>`) and then read and decode on the remote end to display the video.